# Mathematical objects on crystal meltings and their relation to particle physics

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, particle-physics, string-theory, mathematical-physics

I am a mathematician interested in analytic number theory, and I found the paper [Dimers and Amoebae](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0311005)
, which shows how many mathematical objects like the Mahler measure, the Ronkin function and the Amoebae are related to physical phenomena in thermodynamics coming from understanding the melting of crystal.

All of this is really interesting and I am somewhat managing to understand it, with my small physical background. But then there are many papers that relate the same ideas with many other subjects from physics, like string theory, quiver gauge theory and in general, hard things in particle physics. All of these papers mentioned crystal meltings, but I don't see how these ideas in crystal melting are being applied or are being generalized to particle physics (for example  quiver gauge theory).

I am mostly interested on Theorems 3.5 and 3.6 on [Dimers and Amoebae](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0311005), and my first question is why similar formulas or connections appear in particle physics?

Also, maybe as a second question. I want to know if the formula in Theorem 3.5 which gives the logarithm of the partition function in terms of an integral (which in number theory is called the Mahler measure) is related to the free energy. I have read on the internet that logarithm of partitions functions are related to free energy, but here it appears that there are multiple partitions functions and the one related to free energy is the one in Theorem 3.6 (which is linked to the Ronkin function) and not the one in Theorem 3.5. I don't understand the differences between these two partition functions.

Any comment or correction is welcomed.

**Edit:**  Here are some clarifications: Let $G$ be a $\mathbb{Z}^2$-periodic bipartite planar graph, which depends on the crystal structure. A *dimer configuration* is a perfect matching on this bipartite graph. Let $G_n$ be the quotient of $G$ by the action of $n\mathbb{Z}^2$. It is a finite bipartite graph on a torus $\mathbb{T}^2$.
For bipartite graphs on a torus $\mathbb{T}^2$, one can construct a Kasteleyn matrix $K$. It is a weighted, signed adjacency
matrix for the graph whose determinant is the partition function for matchings on the graph (which is explained in the article with more details). In fact the determinant of the matrix is called Characteristic polynomial in this article.  Now suppose that $K$ is a Kasteleyn matrix for the graph $G_1$. Given any positive parameters $z$ and $w$, in the article they construct a “magnetically altered” Kastelyn matrix $K(z,w)$ from K . I guess they add parameters z and w to the energy of each vertex and then the determinant of the matrix $K(z,w)$ leads to a polynomial in terms of z and w which is denoted by $P(z,w)$.

With the above information, theorem 3.5. in the article is as follows:

The following equality is valid:

$$m(P)= \frac{1}{(2\pi i )^2}\int_{\mathbb{T^2}}\log|P|\frac{dz}{z} \frac{dw}{w}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\log Z(G_n)$$

where $m(P)$ is the Mahler measure of the polynomial $P(z,w)$, and P is the determinant of the Kasteleyn matrix for the graph $G_1$ and $Z(G_n)$ is the partition function associated to $G_n$. They also defined the above limit $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\log Z(G_n)$ to be denoted by $Z(G)$ and is called the partition function per fundamental domain.

The theorem 3.6 is as follows:

The surface tension or free energy of the system is the [Legendre transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation) of the [Ronkin function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amoeba_(mathematics)#Ronkin_function) of the characteristic polynomial P.

Comment: Some advice: Please be more specific. For example, you should first include the equations you are referring to in the question, and where you ask _is the formula in Theorem 3.5 related to free energy?_ ; you should include the formula and state your reasons as to why it should/should not, be related to free energy.

Comment: Do you understand the origin of the equation (1) in Corollary 3.4? Which is something crucial for understanding the subject.

Comment: Hello, I think I understand how to get the equation of Corollary 3.4 from the Theorem and the case n=1, and as this gives a Riemann sum, you get the equality with the integral in Theorem 3.5. My problem is more about the physical interpretation of this normalized partition function.